# C++ press enter to continue

Tags: c++, c++11

Evening, I am looking for a way to get the program to continue on instead of exiting out after asking to press enter to continue. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpAzm.png) I cannot use the list command because im calling function "seatingChart" in another function and having the list command sends me back into the menu. Any suggestions?

```
void seatingChart()
{
    for(row = 0; SEATROWS > row; ++row) // Placeholder for '#'
    for (seat = 0; SEATS > seat; ++seat) // Placeholder for '#'
    theater[row][seat] = '#'; // Applying '#' to the chart

    cout << "\n\t\tSeats";
    cout << "\n        123456789012345678901234567890" << endl; //seat header
    for (int row = 0; SEATROWS > row; ++row) 
    { // Initializing 15 rows
        cout << "\nRow " << setw(2) << row+1 << "\t";
        for (int seat = 0; SEATS > seat; ++seat)
        { // Initializing 30 seats
            cout << theater [row][seat];} //display seating chart
        }

        cout << "\n\n\n\tLegend:\t*  =  Sold";
        cout << "\n\t\t#  =  Available";

        cout << "\n\n\nPress the Enter key to continue.";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
    }
}
```

Entire code below: I get the issue when I input "1" at the menu in order to display the seating chart.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void list();
void getPrices();
void viewSales();
void seatingChart();
void ticketSales();

const int ROWS = 15;
const int COLS = 2;
double price[ROWS][COLS];
const int SEATROWS = 15; //PAT
const int SEATS = 30;//PAT
char theater[SEATROWS][SEATS];//PAT
int row;//PAT
int seat;//PAT
const char TAKEN = '*';//seats taken
const char EMPTY = '#';//seats free

int main()
{

    int x; // Loop counter

    for (x=0; x<ROWS;x++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter ticket price for Row " << setw(2) << (x + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> price[x][COLS];
    }

    list();

    return 0;
}

void list()
{
    int choice;
    cout << "\n\n\n\t\tC++ Theatre" << endl << endl;
    cout << "\n\t1.  View Available Seats";
    cout << "\n\t2.  View Seating Prices";
    cout << "\n\t3.  View Ticket Sales";
    cout << "\n\t4.  Purchase a Ticket";
    cout << "\n\t5.  Exit the Program\n\n";
    cout << "\n\tEnter your choice(1-5):  ";
    cin>>choice;

    while(choice>5 || choice<1)
    {
        cout<<"Choice must be between 1 and 5. Please re-enter:";
        cin>>choice;
    }

    if (choice == 1)
        seatingChart();
    else if (choice == 2)
        getPrices();
    else if (choice == 3)
        viewSales();
    else if (choice == 4)
        ticketSales();

}
void getPrices()
{
    cout<<"\nTicket Prices By Row "<<endl;
    cout<<"      Row    Price"<<endl;
    cout<<"      ---    -----"<<endl;

    for (int x= 0; x < ROWS; x++)
    {
        cout<<setw(8)<<x+1<<setw(10);
        cout<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(2)<<price[x][2]<<endl;
    }

    cout<<"\n\n\nPress the Enter key to continue.";

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();

    list();

}

void viewSales()
{
    double sum=0;

    cout<<"\n\nTotal Sales to Date: $"<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(2)<<sum<<"\n\n";

    list();
}

void seatingChart()
{
    for(row = 0; SEATROWS > row; ++row) // Placeholder for '#'
        for (seat = 0; SEATS > seat; ++seat) // Placeholder for '#'
            theater[row][seat] = '#'; // Applying '#' to the chart

    cout << "\n\t\tSeats";
    cout << "\n        123456789012345678901234567890" << endl; //seat header
    for (int row = 0; SEATROWS > row; ++row) { // Initializing 15 rows
        cout << "\nRow " << setw(2) << row+1 << "\t";
        for (int seat = 0; SEATS > seat; ++seat){ // Initializing 30 seats
            cout << theater [row][seat];} //display seating chart
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n\tLegend:\t*  =  Sold";
    cout << "\n\t\t#  =  Available";

    cout << "\n\n\nPress the Enter key to continue.";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}

void ticketSales()
{

    //*********************DISPLAY SEATING**********************************//
    int row;
    int seat;
    char showSeating;
    char anotherTicket = 'N';
    int tickets = 0;
    double totalPrice = 0;
    cout << "\n\t\t        C++ Theatre" << endl;
    cout << "\t\tTicket Purchase Opportunity" << endl << endl;

    cout << "Do you wish to view the chart of available seats \n"
    << "before making your selections (y/n)? ";
    cin  >> showSeating;


    if (toupper(showSeating) == 'Y')
        seatingChart();
    /*------------------Working display and working taken------------------------------*/
    do
    {
        cout << "\nPlease enter desired row number (1-" << ROWS << "): ";
        cin >> row;

        while (row < 1 || row > ROWS)
        {
            cout << "Row must be between 1 and " << ROWS << ". Please re-enter: ";
            cin  >> row;
        }

        cout << "\nPlease enter desired seat number (1-" << SEATS << "): ";
        cin >> seat;

        while (seat < 1 || seat > SEATS)
        {
            cout << "Seat must be between 1 and " << SEATS << ". Please re-enter: ";
            cin  >> seat;
        }

        row--; seat--; // row and seat indexing starts from 0

        if(theater[row][seat] == TAKEN)
        {
            cout << "This seat is taken! Try another one. \n";
        }

        else{ // and if it is - sell the ticket
            theater[row][seat]==TAKEN;
            tickets++;

            // Need to update seating chart upon purchase

            totalPrice += price[row][COLS];
        }


        cout << "\nWould you like to purchase another seat (y/n)? ";
        cin >> anotherTicket;


        anotherTicket = toupper(anotherTicket);
    }while (anotherTicket == 'Y');
    cout << "\n\nYou have purchased a total of " << tickets << " tickets " << "for a total price of $" << totalPrice;
    list();
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `cin.ignore()` ***and*** `cin.get()`?  Anyway, whatever's causing your program to exit must be in the function calling `seatingChart()` - we can't fix mistakes in the code you haven't posted.  That's why site policy requires you to provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example we can run to reproduce the problem.... see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks for the response, im a noob on this site. let me upload the entire code.

Comment: `I cannot use the list command because im calling function "seatingChart" in another function and having the list command sends me back into the menu.`
What does this mean?

Comment: A [mcve] would go a long way to improving the question.

Comment: I am positive `theater[row][seat]==TAKEN;` doesn't do what you think it does (that's a conditional equivalence check; not an assignment). Further, `totalPrice += price[row][COLS];` is clearly wrong, since `price` is only `COLS` wide in the first place, thus only indexible from 0..COLS-1. This is repeated in multiple places, including `cin >> price[x][COLS]`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you wrap your entire menu code inside a loop and make the exit condition for this loop the user input(in your case typing 5 for exit) the program will terminate as soon as it returns from your seatingchart() function because the list() function will return to main(i.e **seatingchart**() returns to **list**() and **list**() will return to **main**() ). You should do something like this:

```
do
{
   cout << "\n\n\n\t\tC++ Theatre" << endl << endl;
   cout << "\n\t1.  View Available Seats";
   cout << "\n\t2.  View Seating Prices";
   cout << "\n\t3.  View Ticket Sales";
   cout << "\n\t4.  Purchase a Ticket";
   cout << "\n\t5.  Exit the Program\n\n";
   cout << "\n\tEnter your choice(1-5):  ";
   cin>>choice;

   while(choice>5 || choice<1)
   {
      cout<<"Choice must be between 1 and 5. Please re-enter:";
      cin>>choice;
   }

   if (choice == 1)
      seatingChart();
   else if (choice == 2)
      getPrices();
   else if (choice == 3)
      viewSales();
   else if (choice == 4)
       ticketSales();
   else if (choice==5)//this is your exit condition
        break;//will break out of the menu loop
}while(1);//the is your menu loop
```

By the way there are some logical errors in your code, see the comment that are given in the comment section and correct them.